# Love me for whom/who I am

Tags: whom, who

should we rather say 'love me for whom I am', or 'love me for who I am'?
Which is grammatically correct, please?
Thank you.

Comment: "Love me for who I am" is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Don't say "Love me for whom I am."

Most people would consider *whom* "incorrect" from a prescriptive standpoint in this context. There is a prescriptive "rule" saying that a sentence or clause using a form of *to be,* like *I am a human being,* is supposed to have both noun phrases in the same case. This rule isn't actually followed very much in current speech or writing for the pronouns *me, him, her, us, them.* Some people will say that "It is I" is "correct" and "It's me" is "incorrect", but I'd guess that is a minority viewpoint. But the pronoun *whom* is a special case: it is still often considered incorrect to break this rule when using the pronoun *whom.* This means that in "Who I am", *who* is correct because it is a subjective-case form, just like the pronoun *I.*

The external context (*love me for...*) is irrelevant to the use of "who" in "who I am". The usual rule for sentences like this is that the pronoun takes its form based on its role in the most deeply embedded clause that it is a part of.

Comment: i suppose the reason whom is always considered incorrect in the nominative is that it is only used by those who are trying to follow prescriptive grammar

Comment: i don't see why you would use scare quotes around _rule_

Answer (score 1):

I understand the inclination to write *for whom* (which would in some
contexts be correct), but in this case, the who/m belongs to the
subordinate clause *who I am,* while the object of *for* is the whole of
that clause.  And in *who I am,* *who/m* must agree with the subject
(I), which makes it who not whom.

(This is essentially the same as sumelic said.)